# coerced Error making SQL where in reactiverse pgclient Kotlin

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, vert.x, reactive

I have the following code try to do a where in clause in reactiverse pgclient

```
jdbc.rxPreparedQuery("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id IN ($1)", listOf(arrayOf(1)))
```

getting the following error:

> Caused by: io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Values [[Ljava.lang.Integer;@46f45cec] cannot be coerced to [Number]

the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  id          SERIAL       NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT table_name PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I am using `reactive-pg-client-0.11.1`

Comment: Something doesn't fit, `reactive-pg-client-0.11.1` shouldn't accept `listOf()` in the first place. Could you post how you initialize your client, eg `val jdbc = ...` and what imports you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to use the `ANY` operator:

```
jdbc.rxPreparedQuery("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = ANY($1)", arrayOf(1))
```